# Select label from document without knowing id

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've been working on the modification of an iframe using javascript. The iframe contains [this form](http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/mrlinux.tumblr.com)

What I want to be able to do is retrieve information from the label; however it doesn't have an ID. is there any way I could get javascript to get the input button by ID, and have it analyze the label assigned to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

casablanca's way is the best way if you only know the button ID.

Depending on what else you might know, other things might be quicker. If, for instance, you know that it is inside a DIV that you know the ID of, and you know that it is the only label inside that DIV, then you could do something like

```
var label = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('label')[0];
```

If you know that it'll always be the only label with the same parent as your button, you could write

```
var label = document.getElementById('button').parentNode.getelementsByTagName('label')[0];
```

Basically, a broad set of solutions might be optimal depending on what assumptions you can afford to make. If you only know what you've told us in the question, then casablanca's iteration is the way to go.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `parentNode` instead of `parent()`?

Comment: @cas: bah, you're right, i've grown too used to this jquery stuff :) edited. and thanks.

Comment: The second string worked, but how can I get this to work with an iFrame? The link provided, as I said, was just the content of the iFrame.

Comment: and you're executing the script from outside the iframe? if the page loaded in the iframe is on the same domain, you'll be able to access it as `document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('buttonInIframe')`. if they iframe is showing a page from a site that is not hosted on the same domain, you will not be able to interact with it through javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You could go through all `label` elements and find the one whose `for` attribute matches your button ID:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
var label = null;
var buttonID = '...';
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
  if (labels[i].htmlFor == buttonID) {
    label = labels[i];
    break;
  }
// "label" now refers to the label you're looking for
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend investigating [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this sort of manipulation. I'm sure that you probably don't want to introduce a whole Javascript framework to solve this one little issue, but if you learn it you will find that Javascript programming becomes much easier.

Assuming that @casablanca's answer is correct, you could accomplish the same thing in jQuery with the following code:

```
var label = $('label[for="..."]').get(0);
```

(Or something like that. My syntax may be off. :-)

Comment: The html attribute is `for`. in javascript, the property is called `htmlFor` because `for` is a reserved keyword. The jQuery equivalent would simply be `$('label[for=buttonID]');`.

Comment: How could I apply that to content within an iframe?

Comment: @Tommy Ah, is the URL of the iframe in the same domain as the container site? If not then you may be running into cross-domain security restrictions.